# help required regarding memory leak

Tags: linux

my application is causing memory leak of 10mb when the first timeout occurs. Heare i am using linux timer functions (timer_create etc.,).
For the subsequent timeouts no issue is there. I doubt some problem with linux timers.
I debugged it with valgrind and purify. Even these tools are of no help to me. In both the tools, memory leaked is shown as few kb's. But my application is causing memory leak of 10mb for the first timeout.
If anybody faced this problem earlier, please help me.

Comment: what about showing some code and explain more details and tell us in which language you're writing?

Comment: Have you tried using valgrind on your app? You might find its output useful.

Comment: and why you think it's a memory leak..

Comment: First of all, tell us how you came up with the 10MB figure. Then, provide a minimal example that illustrates the problem.

Comment: @Simone,                                                                why i feel it as memory leak is, the increase memory at runtime is not getting reduced.

Comment: @jim brssom                                                           i have observed my application's memory usage with top command. I simulated timeout of the request that comes to my application. After the first timeout, the vrt in top command's output is increasing by 10mb

Comment: @abcd but it's not even increased each time. Maybe the system is just loading some dynamic library.

Comment: @abcd It is only a memory leak if the 10MB is not released when your program terminates. Simone's guess is probably right that the increased memory usage is from a dynamic library being loaded. If that The fact that your runtime memory usage does not decrease during the run just means that the memory is only free just before program termination.

Answer (score 2):

To find out which bits of you code is causing the leak (if any), compile your code to include debug symbols (i.e. include `-g` flag if you're using `gcc`), then run your program via [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

```
valgrind --leak-check=full ./your_program
```

The run will take a little longer than usual, but when your program ends, the output from valgrind should tell you how much memory you've leaked and where the cuplrits are.

Sample output:

```
==10934== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10934==     in use at exit: 10 bytes in 10 blocks
==10934==   total heap usage: 10 allocs, 0 frees, 10 bytes allocated
==10934== 
==10934== 10 bytes in 10 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==10934==    at 0x4024F20: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==10934==    by 0x8048402: main (a.c:8)
==10934== 
==10934== LEAK SUMMARY:
==10934==    definitely lost: 10 bytes in 10 blocks
==10934==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10934==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10934==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10934==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

#### update

Since you're already using valgrind, perhaps you could try using the Massif tool that comes with it. It should be able to paint a more accurate picture of memory usage (compare to simply watching top).

Check out [this tutorial](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/valgrind/valgrind_102.html) to see how it can be used. You may need some additional options to get a sensible graph depending on the runtime and mem usage of your program. Some useful options are described a few pages later in the tutorial.

Good luck.

Comment: @Isc,                                                                 I have done that the following is the leak summary.                   812 ==18074== LEAK SUMMARY:               
813 ==18074==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.       
814 ==18074==      possibly lost: 3,424 bytes in 20 blocks.   
815 ==18074==    still reachable: 10,422 bytes in 47 blocks.   
816 ==18074==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
it is fiew kb's. I can't understand how 10mb is getting leaked

Comment: @Isc,                                                       what could be the reason in your example for definitely lost 10 bytes?

Comment: In the example code, I intentionally allocated memory without freeing it. The line number shown in valgrind's output will correspond to the line number where memory was allocated.

Comment: @Isc                                                                 but in my application there is no definitely lost momory. adding possibly lost and still reachable, it is coming out to be around 15 kb. but i am not getting how vrt in top command is getting inceased by 10mb.

Comment: Then it's not a memory leak. The rogue 10MB that you claim is leaked is probably memory used by loaded libraries. See comments in Q.